# Changed user name but files are now unaccessible

Tags: macos, user-account

I changed the home user name using http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1428 and now search in Mail and Finder only show me files I've accessed since the change. This is a major issue for me.

How can I fix this OR revert back safely?

I use Time Machine but my attempt to restore to the time before I made the change did not work.

Comment: Just to be clear, did you change the account name, the user folder name or both?

Comment: It's been a few days so what I can say for sure is that I followed the guide above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Macintosh HD< Users< you should find your account name here < desktop< right click get info< give your self permission  then apply this permission to all encloused items>

Comment: I'd tried the above but when I go to mail - search I still only get mail I've opened since I made the change in the results list, same with finder. Is there possibly an index file or something that needs to be deleted or re-indexed. Idk - it's a stretch but I'm really at a loss...

Comment: Try to re index the HDD, this could be done if you go to Apple< system prefrences< spotlight< privacy> then, drag the HDD from desktop and then drag it out, this will trigger the re indexing for your hard drive.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand "drag the HDD from the desktop" drag it to where? Thanks.

Comment: forget about the drag in and drage out. all what you have to do in spotlight< privacy > tab is to add your hdd then remove it and this will trigger the re indexing

Comment: Ding ding ding winner winner! Thank you! Worked for both finder and mail. Happy camper, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that all the permissions are correct on your home folder.
You can use the ACL tool on the Recovery HD to do this:

1. Boot into the Recovery HD using ⌘R.
2. Run `resetpassword` in Terminal (available from Utilities → Terminal).
3. Select your account from the drop-down list.
4. Click the Reset button for **Reset Home Directory Permissions and ACLs**.

Comment: I've tried to do this a few times but the command doesn't boot me into Recovery HD or at least when I go to terminal and type in resetpassword the command isn't recognized...?